# Cursor is not centered in an empty editable anchor with text-align center on firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I have some `anchor` tags as buttons in an application on which `contenteditable` is set to `true` and `text-align` is set to `center`

but if an anchor has no text in it the cursor should be **centered** as the `tex-align` is set to `center` and it works as expected on chrome but on firefox it shows the cursor to extreme left when nothing is typed.

Here's the HTML code:

```css
.editable {
  display: block;
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<a class="editable" contenteditable>
</a>
```

I know it is a bug with Firefox but is there a way to solve this?

Comment: If you start typing you'll see that the cursor does get centered. So it's not really a problem?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware yes after typing first character it gets centered which is a problem I believe cause a button can be 100% of screen width and it may confuse user about what's happening that's what the requirement is

Comment: If you put a `&nbsp` in the editable block it sort of works. You could strip it off later when you process the content. It also works with something innocuous as a `<wbr>`.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, unfortunately, all of them are some HTML files (pages) saved to AWS so there can be many users who will have their own copies of HTML and I can't put a character in their HTML

Comment: @KIKOSoftware this however will work on new created pages which would be fine too. Thanks for that actually.

Comment: You're welcome, just remember that 5% (or more) may not be able to use `contenteditable` in their browser, see: https://caniuse.com/#search=contenteditable

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I understand but we rely on this for this app as this is a sort of CMS. Thanks for sharing a valuable source btw

Comment: @ZeeshanAdil Can you use JS in your code or you're trying to deal with it with just CSS?

Comment: @AdelArmand:  Just CSS would be preferred, but I'm skeptical that's possible and am willing to accept a JS-based solution if necessary.   (I sponsored the bounty.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update

Added placeholder feature and made it more versatile by using [`attr()` CSS function](https://css-tricks.com/css-attr-function-got-nothin-custom-properties/). In order to make it work exactly like a placeholder there's two criteria that dictate the behavior of a placeholder (at least in terms of an HTML input or textarea)

- Must be present when text box is empty. `:empty`
- Must not be present when text box is in focus. `:empty`[:not](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/not/)`(:focus)`

Each anchor can be assigned different placeholders

```html
<a contenteditable data-ph='Placeholder'></a>
<!--Assign tag data-ph attribute and placeholder text as value-->
```

```css
a::before {
  content: attr(data-ph)
/* Add a pseudo-element ::before or ::after and use attr() function and data-ph 
as parameter */
```

### Objective

**Behavior:** Text cursor is aligned ***left*** inside of a contenteditable element with `text-align: center` while empty and in focus.

**Expected:** Text cursor is aligned ***center*** inside of a contenteditable element with `text-align: center` while empty and in focus.

### Pure CSS Solution

1. Assign [`::after` pseudo-element](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/) to anchor.
2. Style `::after` as a blinking cursor.
3. Set [`:empty`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/e/empty/) and [`:focus`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/focus/) pseudo-selectors on `::after` pseudo-element.
4. Hide real cursor with [`caret-color: transparent`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/caret-color/) when anchor is in focus and empty.
5. Assign `display: none` to `::after` when anchor isn't empty.

```css
html {
  font: 300 10pt/1.2 'Segoe UI'
}

.edit {
  display: block;
  min-height: 100px;
  min-width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
}

.edit:empty:not(:focus)::before {
  content: attr(data-ph);
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ccc;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.edit:focus::before {
  display: none;
}

.edit:focus:empty {
  caret-color: transparent;
}

.edit:focus:empty::after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0.1ch;
  height: 2.4rem;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
  background: red;
  animation: blink 0.85s steps(2) infinite;
}

.edit:focus::after {
  display: none;
}

@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<a class='edit' contenteditable data-ph='Placeholder'></a>
<a class='edit' contenteditable data-ph='️'></a>
```

Comment: This is a very clever CSS-only solution (+1) but appears also to adversely impact any placeholder prompt that's present.  If placed via `:after`, the prompt text will blink; if placed via `:before`, the prompt is centered but the insertion point no longer is.  (Run the updated CSS to see the issue.)

Comment: There's no placeholder in example nor is it mentioned in question. If there was a CSS placeholder, then it'll probably be akin to my design using the same selectors. If OP were to provide that extra code, I'd be happy to refactor it to coincide with this answer I got it half in my head already. OIC you added to my answer ok hmm.

Comment: @kjhughes Ok I used `:not(:focus)` see update.

Comment: Background: OP's need was about 4 years ago.  I sponsored the current bounty because I am "Looking for a complete solution to this problem that doesn't introduce its own additional problems."  I appreciate your investigation and solution attempt.  Update: Preliminary trial of your recent update looks promising.

Comment: Ah Ok. I made it so the prompt basically only exists if the anchor is empty and ***not*** in focus.

Answer (score 1):

I did a tiny hack with power of Javascript <3

It's related to the CSS you've provided. Let me know about the result ;)

```js
(function() {
  if (navigator.userAgent.search("Firefox") === -1) { return; }

  const editableElements = document.querySelectorAll('.editable');

  editableElements.forEach((el) => {
    if (!el.innerHTML) {
      const leftPadding = window.getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue('padding-left')
      el.setAttribute('data-padding-left', leftPadding);
      el.style.paddingLeft = `calc(50% + ${leftPadding})`;
      el.style.width = '50%';
    }

    el.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', () => {
      const space = parseFloat(el.style.paddingLeft);
      if (el.innerHTML) {
        el.style.width = '100%';
        el.style.paddingLeft = el.getAttribute('data-left-padding');
      } else {
        const leftPadding = window.getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue('padding-left')
        el.setAttribute('data-padding-left', leftPadding);
        el.style.paddingLeft = '50%';
        el.style.width = '50%';
      }
    });
  });
})();
```

```css
.editable {
  display: block;
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Hack!</title>
</head>
<body>
  <a class="editable" contenteditable></a>
  <a class="editable" contenteditable></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This addresses the initial centering fine (+1) but adversely affects the centering of placeholder text -- run the code snippet with the updated CSS in Firefox to see the issue.